# Check if the mouse and spacebar are pressed at the same time in QML

Tags: qt, input, keyboard, qml, mouse

I'd like to check whether or not the mouse and the spacebar keys are being pressed at the same time using QML

I can check if the mouse and other modifier keys are being pressed. For instance:

```
MouseArea {
  onPressed: {
    if(mouse.modifiers & QT.ControlModifier) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

However, the only way I know how to check for keys is inside of the `Keys.onPressed` handlers. Is there a way to communicate between the `MouseArea onPressed` and `Keys.onPressed` in unison?

Comment: What does _the same time_ mean? There will always be a small gap in time. So you can start a timer when one of them was pressed and check the time difference when the second one will do.

Comment: @folibis Same time meaning detect if the two keys are held down concurrently. The part that's tripping me up is where to place the Keys.onPressed handler. Since I (assume) I can't nest it inside of the mouse area block. I need to be able to pass some information between the MouseArea onPressed and the Keys.onPressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example code of the same issue:

**MyItem.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
    id: element
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "orange"
    signal mySignal()
    property int myState: MyItem.Bits.None
    enum Bits {
        None = 0,
        MouseOn = 1,
        KeyOn = 2,
        AllOn = 3
    }

    function checkBits()
    {
        if(element.myState === MyItem.Bits.AllOn)
        {
            element.mySignal();
            element.myState = MyItem.Bits.None;
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: {
            element.myState |= MyItem.Bits.MouseOn;
            element.checkBits();
        }
        onReleased: {
            element.myState &= ~MyItem.Bits.MouseOn;
            element.checkBits();
        }
    }
    Keys.onSpacePressed: {
        element.myState |= MyItem.Bits.KeyOn;
        element.checkBits();
    }
    Keys.onReleased: {
        if(element.myState & MyItem.Bits.KeyOn)
        {
            element.myState &= ~MyItem.Bits.KeyOn;
            element.checkBits();
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400

    MyItem {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        focus: true
        onMySignal: {
            console.log("My Signal")
        }
    }
}
```

`MySignal` will be fired on simultaneously Mouse and Space clicking.
*Note, `enum` requires Qt 5.10 or higher*